# Android development pulling data from a website and formatting into an app

Tags: java, android, web, wiki

Hello I am new to android programming, I haven't started writing the code for my app idea yet but I am in planning and learning the Android OS.  I was wondering if there is a way that I could pull data from a site such as a wiki from wikia.com and format it in an android app and how would I go about doing this?

I want to pull data such as the information under the different sections, for example take a band history such as The Beatles,  I want to pull the History section, Discography, stuff like that and format it to look good in my app.  Is there a way to do this?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

- APIs
- Scraping/reformatting the site

If a website has an API you can simply use that to query the website and get the data you need. If not you'll be forced to download the html and scrape out the relevant information.

Scraping is considered a legal gray and most websites don't appreciate it, especially if you plan on redistributing the content of the site.